# How to use cache in c++?

Tags: c++, file, caching, encryption

I have a task to create an application for encoding and decoding using Atbash cipher. I have done the encoding/decoding thing but another part of the task is to cache the already encoded/decoded strings. Cache should be printable with standard stream operators and should be able to be stored and loaded in/from a file. Could someone help me to do it? Thanks in advance! This is my code by now:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    string Atbash_cipher(string message) 
    {
        string upperAlpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        string reverseUpperAlpha = "ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
        string lowerAlpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        string reverseLowerAlpha = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
        string cipher = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (message[i] >= 32 && message[i] <= 64 && message[i] >= 173 && message[i] <= 176)
            {
              cipher += message[i];
            }
            if (message[i] >= 'A' && message[i] <= 'Z')
            {
              for (int j = 0; j < upperAlpha.length(); j++) {
                if (message[i] == upperAlpha[j]) 
                {
                  cipher += reverseUpperAlpha[j];
                  break;
                }
            }
      }
    else 
   {
        for (int j = 0; j < lowerAlpha.length(); j++) 
        {
            if (message[i] == lowerAlpha[j]) 
            {
                cipher += reverseLowerAlpha[j];
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
}
return cipher;
}
void menu()
{
    int choice;
    string message;
    do
    {
        cout << "1. Encrypt message" << endl << "2. Decrypt message" << endl << "0. Exit" << 
endl << "Your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter message to encrypt: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, message);
            cout<< Atbash_cipher(message) <<endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter message to encrypt: ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, message);
            cout << Atbash_cipher(message) << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 0);
}
int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your case cache would be a simple `std::map<std::string, std::string>` that maps input to encoded output (or vice versa if you want).

Comment: When developing a cache class, especially as a beginner, it is useful to start with a simple cache of size 0 (it's always possible that the item you want is not in the cache, caller should handle that), then move to an infinite cache (still not very hard), and only then implement a finite cache. Only the last type of cache needs a smart replacement algorithm.